# Type MatDateRangePicker is not assignable to type MatDatepickerPanel<MatDatepickerControl<Date>, DateRange<Date>, Date>

Tags: html, angular, webstorm

All works done. Error only in IDE.

> Angular - 13.0.2,
> WebStorm - 2021.3

What could be the problem?

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]='picker' [min]='currentDate'>
                                         ^^^^^^#Type MatDateRangePicker is not assignable to type MatDatepickerPanel<MatDatepickerControl<Date>, DateRange<Date>, Date> 
      <input matStartDate formControlName='startDate' placeholder='Start date'>
      <input matEndDate formControlName='endDate' placeholder='End date'>
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]='picker'></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable this strict type checking like this:

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
```